# What happens when using an SSH key for git authentication then HTTP for clone?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

It may be that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something, but what's happening with respect to network protocols and authentication when I do the following:

Add an SSH key pair in git client and server (e.g. Bitbucket), then `git clone http://example.git`

- Is the SSH key in the HTTP request, so authentication and cloning are both taking place over HTTP with an SSH key attached?
- Is the authentication with SSH, then somehow the clone is associated but executed over HTTP?
- Is the authentication with SSH, then the clone is HTTP inside SSH?
- Am I unintentionally authenticated some other way, so SSH keys aren't even coming into play?
- Something else I haven't considered...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git can use different protocols. Local files, ssh, http(s) (smart or dumb), and the git protocol. You choose the protocol by the URL you choose.

Each protocol uses its own authentication method, or none at all. The ssh keys are only used if you use the ssh protocol. Not if you use http.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the url you use to communicate with the remote repository.

By `git clone http://example.git`, the url is `http://example.git`, so the http protocol and authentication are used. The url used in `git clone` will be stored as the value of the default remote `origin`. The command `git remote` can create, delete, edit and list remotes, including `origin`. A remote has two values, one for push and the other for fetch, but in most cases both are the same.

In the occasions where the url is needed, for example `git fetch`, `git push` and `git ls-remote`, a remote that has stored the url can be used. It’s shorter and easier to remember. If no remote has stored the url, then you need to create one and then use it, or use the url directly. In the cloned repository, `git pull origin master` is equivalent to `git pull http://example.git master`.

As long as the remote repository allows, you can use other protocols. In the cloned repository, if the ssh url is `ssh://$username@$host:29418/example.git`, then you can run `git remote add sshori ssh://$username@$host:29418/example.git` to create a new remote `sshori`. Now `git pull sshori master` is equivalent to `git pull  ssh://$username@$host:29418/example.git master`, and the ssh protocol and authentication are used. At the same time, the existing `origin` is free to use. In real cases, different remotes are usually used to make tunnels between the local repository and different multiple remote repositories.

Answer (score 1):

With that you are not using an ssh key at all, in order to use an ssh key, you need to pass a username.

If you don't have any ssh key in default directory, in this case it would probably be ~/.ssh/id_rsa.

Then your client will check together with the public key, and if there is a match, it will let you clone.

In order to use ssh, you need to do `username@whatever.whatever:/whatever/whatever.git.`. whatever.whatever being the domain name which leads to an ip-adress. This is then using SSH. And will look for an SSH key.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone and push using SSH or HTTP - as long the server supports it (Bitbucket supports both).

SSH keys are for SSH authentication only